# What is a promise object in R?

Tags: r

Can anyone give me an explanation of a promise object in R? I'm still new to R. So thanks in advance for keeping it simple (if possible).

I couldn't find a brief description nor in literature neither at web.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#capturing-expressions

Comment: If you don't know what it is, in which context did you see the term used? Outside of the R-devel mailing list you rarely see people discussing promises.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Promise objects are used within packages to make objects available to users without loading them into the memory. Unfortunately, it is not possible to determine if an object is a promise object, nor it is possible to figure out the environment in which it was created. 
For example : You can create a promise object to delay evaluation of a variable until it is (first) needed. You can do it using *delayedAssign* function.

```
 x <- 1
 y <- 2
 z <- 3
 delayedAssign("v", c(x, y, z))
 x <- 5
 v
#[1] 5 2 3
```

Reference : **http://130.132.212.207/mediawiki/images/0/09/R_in_a_Nutshell.pdf**

Comment: `is_promise` in the pryr package can report if an object is a promise without forcing it.  Also see `promise_info` in the same package.

Answer (score -3):

Promise is an object that generally contains data loaded from a package. It becomes a dataframe as soon as you use it. It is a promise object from when you load it until you use it.

Comment: While this is not generally true, it is indeed true for a data set that is a promise object.